# Como puedo cambiar el valor del parametro?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Al momento de intentar cambiar el valor de la variable `running` me indica en el propio VS que la variable no esta siendo accedida, requiero cambiar el valor de la variable que viene desde otra parte por referencia:

**main.py:**

```
import pygame

from public.modules.classes.Screen import Screen

FPS = 75
SCREEN_DIM = (1280, 720)
SCREEN_COLOR = (0, 0, 0, 0)

def main():
    # pygame setup
    pygame.init()

    screen = Screen(SCREEN_DIM, SCREEN_COLOR, FPS)
    screen.init()

    while screen.running:
        #screen.paint()
        screen.listenForEvents()
        #screen.graphics.drawCircle('red', (200, 200), 20)

        # flip() the display to put your work on screen
        pygame.display.flip()

        screen.tick()

    pygame.quit()


main()
```

**Screen.py (Minimizado):**

```
import pygame

from .Graphics import Graphics
from .EventHandler import EventHandler

class Screen:

    def __init__(self, SCREEN_DIM = (1280, 720), SCREEN_COLOR = (0, 0, 0, 0), FPS = 75) -> None:
        #Constants
        self.FPS = FPS
        self.SCREEN_DIM = SCREEN_DIM
        self.SCREEN_COLOR = SCREEN_COLOR
        
        #Variables
        self.running = ~(True)

    def init(self):
         self.screen  = pygame.display.set_mode(self.SCREEN_DIM)
         self.clock   = pygame.time.Clock()
         self.eventHandler = EventHandler()
         self.graphics = Graphics(self.screen)

    def tick(self):
        self.clock.tick(self.FPS / 1000)

    def listenForEvents(self):
        self.eventHandler.listenCloseEvent(self.running)
```

**EventHandler.py:**

```
import pygame.event

class EventHandler:

    #Constructor
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    #Evento para cerrar la ventana
    def listenCloseEvent(self, running):
        # poll for events
        # pygame.QUIT event means the user clicked X to close your window
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = ~(True)
```

La propiedad hace parte de la clase `Screen` se llama `running` y debe ser cambiada desde `EventHandler`.

Comment: Tengo una suposición: querés modificar una variable global desde esa función? Por que al no usar "global running", python y vscode creerían que tu intención es crear la variable local running. Y si querés establecer algo a False (suponiendo que controlas un loop de pygame) se hace con running = False. Si mis suposiciones son incorrectas, recomiendo que muestres un código completo (no es necesario que sea el original) donde vscode te diga eso.

Comment: @Dante S. Es una propiedad que viene desde otra clase, es una propiedad de una clase, no es una variable global de otro archivo.

Comment: Para acceder a una propiedad (suponiendo que hablamos del resultado decorador property) se requiere poder acceder a una instancia de la clase que tiene dicha.

Comment: Mejor editare mi pregunta y pondre un codigo mas extendido.

Comment: Por otro lado estoy teniendo problemas al momento de que el codigo funcione bien de esta forma, parece como que si al desacoplar el codigo en varias partes el pygame no funcione correctamente y se trabe al ejecutar.

Comment: segun esto self.running = ~(True) running es falso, la verdad no entiendo porque no haces self.running = False directamente. igual cuando llegues al while no se ejecutara

Comment: Hola Riven, si ejecutas **vaca = ~(True)** y luego **print( vaca )**, te encontrarás con la desagradable sorpresa de que imprime "**-2**", con "False", imprime "**-1**", no creo que sea lo que esperas, si estoy en lo cierto, sigue las indicaciones de @DanielBriceño... por otro lado, debes pasar como parámetro el objeto **Screen** y luego usar: **screen.running = True**.

Comment: @MarcePuente que sorpresa un -2. si, efectivamente no es lo que espero, supongo sera usar lo convencional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python no funciona como estás pensando.

Cuando hacés self.running, en realidad, estás obteniendo el valor referenciado que está en memoria, NO una propiedad que puedas modificar y cambie el atributo original (esa caracteristica no existe en Python).

Piensa en las variables (al menos en Python) como nombres que le das a un objeto. Al hacer algo como `running = self.running` (que es lo que pasa en el fondo cuando pasas argumentos a una función), simplemente le estás dando al valor referenciado en self.running el nombre running.

Lo que está sucediendo, es la creación de una variable local (que solo existe dentro de la función) llamada running. Y como a esa variable local, que no tiene relación con self.running, no la usás en ninguna parte de la función y se borra sin ser usada, vscode te lo avisa para evitar código de más.

También diría que tengas en cuenta que, tal y como estás diseñando tu event handler, pareciera que vas a recorrer la cola de eventos entera varias veces buscando un solo tipo de evento. Esto implica varias iteraciones que ralentizarán tu juego y pueden reducirse a una sola.

---

Un truco simple de entender que se me ocurre es tener un diccionario con el tipo de evento y su correspondiente función como valor. De paso, te ofresco una de las muchas soluciones al problema actual.

**EventHandler**

```
class EventHandler:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.handlers = {}
        self.handlers[pygame.QUIT] = self.listenCloseEvent

    def listenCloseEvent(self, game):
        game.running = False

    def listenForEvents(self, game):
        # poll for events
        # pygame.QUIT event means the user clicked X to close your window
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type in self.handlers:
                self.handlers[event.type](game)
                
                if not game.running:
                    break
```

**listenForEvents**

```
def listenForEvents(self):
    self.eventHandler.listenCloseEvent(self)
```

---

Si te cuesta entender lo de tratar funciones como objetos, podés hardcodear cada tipo de evento dentro del for:

**EventHandler**

```
class EventHandler:
    def listenCloseEvent(self, game):
        game.running = False

    def listenForEvents(self, game):
        # poll for events
        # pygame.QUIT event means the user clicked X to close your window
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.listenCloseEvent(game)

            if not game.running:
                break
```

**listenForEvents**

```
def listenForEvents(self):
    self.eventHandler.listenForEvents(self)
```

Comment: Es un buen punto, la forma en la que propones manejar los eventos, justo algo asi haria en js.